# Low-graphics mode error during installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, graphics

I downloaded ubuntu 14.04 and made a bootable USB stick. When try to install it or even try ubuntu without istallation i get "The system is running in low graphics mode" error. I cannot click ok, enter does not work (i guess whole keyboard). Literally nothing i can do.
Would appreciate any help. Haven't tried ubuntu 15 yet.

This question refers to non-installed system.

Windows 8.1
Asus r556ld
Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Comment: this refers to already installed ubuntu - i can do nothing no matter if i chose install ubuntu or try ubuntu without installing

Comment: You can use `nomodeset` kernel parameter to boot, then you can install the system and install a video driver. http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/167850

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/167850) to boot with `nomodeset` kernel parameter when booting from LiveUSB.

Then you will be able to install the system.

If the installed system still does start GUI, then you can use same method.

After all is installed you will probably need to install a proprietary video driver, because it looks like open source drivers do not support your video adapter well.