# Can't install Ubuntu on ASUS z97-a 3.1 mobo

Tags: system-installation, usb, hardware, asus, motherboard

I can boot into my USB from my BIOS, but when I select *Install* or *Try Ubuntu without installing* I lose video output. I have tried all of my USB ports and using a USB hub to bring it down to USB 2.0, but that didn't work.

Specs:

- mobo: ASUS z97-a USB 3.1
- CPU: Intel Core i5 4690K
- RAM 16GB 1866 MHz
- GPU: g1 gaming GTX 970

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freezing Ubuntu while installing from live usb](http://askubuntu.com/questions/670887/freezing-ubuntu-while-installing-from-live-usb)

Comment: You need to boot with nomodeset and install a driver.

Comment: Also see this http://askubuntu.com/a/643953/167850

Comment: And this is the best match for a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/672049/changing-display-settings-during-ubuntu-15-04-installation

Comment: Another Asus thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503168/minor-problems-with-using-an-asus-z97-a-motherboard I also have an Asus-AR which uses the same UEFI. Have you updated to the latest version? You need to change to "other" not Windows in UEFI, and in CSM settings change to UEFI only. Best to change fast boot to normal, so you can get into UEFI to make corrections. If you udpate UEFI, it resets to defaults so do screen shot or write down all changes for next UEFI update. You will need the nomodeset as discussed and should then install nVidia drivers from Ubuntu's new PPA.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323500

It may be that your CD/DVD/BD player is plugged into the wrong connector.  Check the manual for your motherboard.  It's possible that you have your optical drive plugged into an ASMedia connector instead of a SATA connector.  ASMedia only supports AHCI mode (data drives).